# Scroll a part of a fixed container with nested flex containers (vue/tailwind)

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, scrollbar, fixed, tailwind-css

I have some overlay container with fixed attribute and inside i need three flex col divs next to each other. In the first flex-col div i have at the bottom a div which contains two compoenents among themselves (flex-col) i need to make scrollable. But i cant find any way to archive that container to become scrollable. Here is my code:

```
<div
class="fixed top-10 bottom-10 h-4/5 flex flex flex-col justify-center left-10 right-10 z-1003 overflow-hidden">
<div class="w-full h-full bg-white left-10 right-10 shadow-rb rounded-lg">
  <Some HEader (not visible in my attached photo)
  />
  <div class="flex flex-row mx-8 my-6">
    <div class="flex-1">
      <div class="flex flex-col">
        <SomeUnscrollableContent/>
        <img :src="someImage" class="w-full h-52 mt-4" />
        <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 w-full h-full z-1001">
          <div
            class="w-full h-full top-0 bottom-0 left-0 overflow-y-scroll"
          >
          **HERE IS MY SCROLLABLE CONTENT**
          <Component 1 />
          <Component 2 />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 flex-1 border-solid border border-black-normal">
      <div class="flex flex-col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 flex-1 border-solid border border-black-normal">
      <div class="flex flex-col"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried multiple attempts also setting the div before the scrollable content to absolute, which results that the content goes the whole flex container width.
Has someone an idea? This is how it should look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below given classes. [Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/tDN2jzb5n1)

```
<div class="flex min-h-screen max-h-screen overflow-hidden p-4">
  <div class="flex flex-1">
    <div class="flex flex-1 bg-blue-100">
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-1">
        <div class="flex h-48 bg-gray-50">1</div>
        <div class="flex h-48 bg-gray-100">2</div>
        <div class="flex flex-1 bg-gray-200 overflow-x-hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores eos aliquid tenetur at reprehenderit rem fugit provident sed, est eligendi animi quo quod suscipit labore tempora mollitia ratione ut quasi? Praesentium fugiat rem, sed, animi veniam esse expedita, distinctio exercitationem aperiam rerum magnam vel doloremque! Aliquid eos minima atque soluta voluptatum, saepe in aliquam numquam quo inventore, dolores tempora omnis. Eveniet exercitationem temporibus aspernatur quibusdam tenetur! Debitis nisi facere necessitatibus blanditiis distinctio atque repudiandae ipsum autem. Consequatur maiores ut illum aliquam, non, numquam provident explicabo ex, vero in sit amet? Expedita optio veniam nulla odio, culpa aut officia excepturi iste! Quo veniam distinctio soluta corrupti? Ex quidem nihil, aspernatur soluta dignissimos optio, natus at totam blanditiis dolores inventore mollitia officia? Deserunt tenetur eaque iste, non et id molestiae vitae ex quisquam aspernatur eum, voluptates vero, perspiciatis molestias nam ipsam exercitationem qui nemo ratione ab consectetur blanditiis quaerat debitis ad? Repudiandae.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-1">22</div>
    <div class="flex flex-1">33</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately your example isnt working for me, because the overflow content goes out of my defined fixed container of h-4/5. So im able to scroll, but the content overflows that 4/5 height container.
And also, something i forgot to mention: In my scrollable content i need to display two different components in a flew-col not in a flew-row container.
What im trying to archive is: My scrollable content of two components should be scrollable but always staty inside my fixed outer container of a 4/5 screen height. This whole thing should behave like some overlay.